# Updating values in one row depending on another value's row

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to update the value of one row - depending on another value's row using jQuery.

For example:

If **Room Allocation = Pending** then the buttons Edit and Cancel appear under Actions
If **Room Allocation != Pending** then the buttons Edit and Decline appear under Actions

How do I go about doing this?

Here is a fiddle I've included: http://jsfiddle.net/S9Gwy/

Here is my code so far:

```
    $('.results_tbl').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": true
    });

        /*====================================

        determining whether cancel or decline
        button is going to appear depending on
        room allocation status

        =====================================*/

    // find all the booking rows

    var bookingRows = $('table tr.booking');

    // stash a reference to the row

    bookingRows.each(function () {
        var row = $(this);

        // if you can add a class of 'pending' to the status <td>, this becomes even cleaner and nicer...

        // check the contents of the status column

        if (row.find('td.status').text().toLowerCase() == 'pending') {

            // add a class to the row so the CSS can do its thing...

            row.addClass('pending');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first (row-level) solution might be this:

```
tr.booking .cancelall {
    display: none;
}

tr.booking.pending .cancelall {
    display: inline-block;
}

tr.booking.pending .declineall {
    display: none;
}
```